# Por que el boton de clase .comprar-smartphone2-grande no sube a pesar del margin?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando hacer una tienda virtual que sea resposive para practicar mi html y mi css.

Disculpen lo feo que es el codigo, apenas estoy empezando a programar, denme cualquier sugerencia para escribir buen codigo con html y css y que pueda ser codigo reutilizable y facil de leer. siento que no esta bien la manera en que muevo los elementos, por favor díganme como se hace de manera correcta. en este caso tengo muchos problemas al añadirle estilos al  que contiene los productos y generalmente suele verse bien (aunque creo que no se hace asi, incluso en el codigo se ve que intente de mover los elementos de 2 maneras distintas, una con position relative y otra position absolute) espero que puedan ayudarme

HTML

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Tecnoven</title>
    <link  rel="icon"   href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_grande.css" media="screen and (min-width:1023px)">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_mini.css" media="screen and (max-width:1022px)">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

        <header class="header-grande">
        
            <nav>
                <img class="logo-grande" src="logo.png">

                <ul class="lista-nav-grande">
                    <li> <a href= #inicio > Inicio </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href= #productos > Productos </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href= #contacto > Contacto </a> </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <p class="siguenos-grande">Siguenos en nuestras redes!</p>

            <a class="logofb-grande" title="Perfil de Tecnoven en Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/DAGF1712">
                <img class="logofb-grande" src="logofb.png" alt="Perfil de Tecnoven en Facebook"> </a>

            <a class="logoig-grande" title="Perfil de Tecnoven en Instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com/DAGF1712">
                <img class="logoig-grande" src="logoig.png" alt="Perfil de Tecnoven en Instagram"> </a>

        </header>

        <main class="main-grande">

            <h2 class="productos-nuevos-grande">PRODUCTOS NUEVOS</h2>
            <h3 class="smartphones-grande">Telefonos inteligentes</h3>

            <div class="smartphone1-grande">
                <h3 class="titulo-smartphone1-grande">Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro</h3>

                <a class="foto-smartphone1-grande" title="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro" href="#">
                <img class="foto-smartphone1-grande" src="smartphone1.jpg" alt="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro"> </a>

                <table class="tabla-smartphone1-grande">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ESPECIFICACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Almacenamiento</td>
                            <td>32GB/64GB/128GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memoria RAM</td>
                            <td>6GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara frontal</td>
                            <td>8 Megapixeles</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara trasera</td>
                            <td>4 camaras: 32mp,8mp,5mp,2mp</td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="precio-smartphone1-grande">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>230$</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <a class="comprar-smartphone1-grande" href="#">Comprar</a>
                
            </div>

            <div class="smartphone2-grande">
                <h3 class="titulo-smartphone2-grande">Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro</h3>

                <a class="foto-smartphone2-grande" title="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro" href="#">
                <img class="foto-smartphone2-grande" src="smartphone1.jpg" alt="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro"> </a>

                <table class="tabla-smartphone2-grande">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ESPECIFICACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Almacenamiento</td>
                            <td>32GB/64GB/128GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memoria RAM</td>
                            <td>6GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara frontal</td>
                            <td>8 Megapixeles</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara trasera</td>
                            <td>4 camaras: 32mp,8mp,5mp,2mp</td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="precio-smartphone2-grande">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>230$</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <a class="comprar-smartphone2-grande" href="#">Comprar</a>
                
            </div>

        </main>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: small-caps 100% serif;
}

.header-grande {
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0.4vw solid #04c4a4;
    height: 18%;
}

.logo-grande{
    width: 20%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 3%;
    top: 3%;
}

.lista-nav-grande{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.lista-nav-grande li{
    position: relative;
    left: 25%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    margin:2%;
}

.lista-nav-grande a{
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    padding: 10%;
    border:1px solid #04c4a4;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
 }

 .lista-nav-grande a:hover{
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #999;
    background-color: #04c4a430;
 }

 .siguenos-grande{
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-style: italic;
    position: absolute;
    left: 67%;
    top:7%;
 }

 .logofb-grande {
    width: 22%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 70%;
    top: 3.7%;
 }

 .logoig-grande {
    width: 19.3%;
    position:absolute;
    left: 77%;
    top: 5.3%;
 }

.main-grande{
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.productos-nuevos-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.7vw;
}

.smartphones-grande{
    font-size: 2vw;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

/* Estilos 1er producto */

.smartphone1-grande{
    border: 3px solid #04c4a4;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 5.5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 85%;
    height: 50%;
}

.titulo-smartphone1-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 100%;
}

.foto-smartphone1-grande{
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.tabla-smartphone1-grande{
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 33%;
    bottom: 18%

}

.precio-smartphone1-grande{
    font-size: 2.8vw;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 77%;
    bottom: 30%;
}

.comprar-smartphone1-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    left: 76.4%;
    bottom: 17%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1%;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    background-color: #04c4a450;
    border-radius: 28%;
    border:1px solid black;
    color: black;
}

.comprar-smartphone1-grande:hover{
    color: blue;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #999;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

/* Estilos 2do producto */

  .smartphone2-grande{
    border: 3px solid #04c4a4;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 5.5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 85%;
    height: 50%;
}

.titulo-smartphone2-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 100%;
}

.foto-smartphone2-grande{
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.tabla-smartphone2-grande{
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 30%;
    bottom:58%;

}

.precio-smartphone2-grande{
    font-size: 2.8vw;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    left: 83%;
    bottom: 120%;
}

.comprar-smartphone2-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 82.5%;
    margin-bottom: 130%;
    padding: 1%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    background-color: #04c4a450;
    border-radius: 28%;
    border:1px solid black;
    color: black;
}

.comprar-smartphone2-grande:hover{
    color: blue;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #999;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que creo que necesitas es comprender el sistema de contenedores de la etiqueta `<div>`.
Lo que he hecho ha sido separarte los dos productos en dos divs diferentes, y luego aplicar un `padding` al contenedor del div para que el botón no quede pegado al contenedor.

Solo he puesto la parte de los contenedores, he omitido toda la parte superior del `header` y `nav` porque es irrelevante.

```css
.main-grande{
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.productos-nuevos-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.7vw;
}

.smartphones-grande{
    font-size: 2vw;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

/* Estilos 1er producto */

.smartphone1-grande{
    border: 3px solid #04c4a4;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 5.5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 85%;
    height: 50%;
}

.titulo-smartphone1-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 100%;
}

.foto-smartphone1-grande{
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.tabla-smartphone1-grande{
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 33%;
    bottom: 18%

}

.precio-smartphone1-grande{
    font-size: 2.8vw;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 77%;
    bottom: 30%;
}

.comprar-smartphone1-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    left: 76.4%;
    bottom: 17%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1%;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    background-color: #04c4a450;
    border-radius: 28%;
    border:1px solid black;
    color: black;
}

.comprar-smartphone1-grande:hover{
    color: blue;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #999;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }

/* Estilos 2do producto */

.smartphone2-grande {
    border: 3px solid #04c4a4;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 5.5%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 85%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 20px 0px;
}

.titulo-smartphone2-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 100%;
}

.foto-smartphone2-grande{
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.tabla-smartphone2-grande{
    font-size: 1.6vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 30%;
    bottom:58%;

}

.precio-smartphone2-grande{
    font-size: 2.8vw;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    left: 83%;
    bottom: 120%;
}

.comprar-smartphone2-grande{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 82.5%;
    margin-bottom: 130%;
    padding: 1%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    background-color: #04c4a450;
    border-radius: 28%;
    border:1px solid black;
    color: black;
}

.comprar-smartphone2-grande:hover{
    color: blue;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 8px #999;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
```

```html
            <div class="smartphone2-grande">
                <h3 class="titulo-smartphone2-grande">Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro</h3>

                <a class="foto-smartphone2-grande" title="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro" href="#">
                <img class="foto-smartphone2-grande" src="smartphone1.jpg" alt="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro"> </a>

                <table class="tabla-smartphone2-grande">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ESPECIFICACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Almacenamiento</td>
                            <td>32GB/64GB/128GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memoria RAM</td>
                            <td>6GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara frontal</td>
                            <td>8 Megapixeles</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara trasera</td>
                            <td>4 camaras: 32mp,8mp,5mp,2mp</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="precio-smartphone2-grande">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>230$</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <a class="comprar-smartphone2-grande" href="#">Comprar</a>
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="smartphone2-grande">
                <h3 class="titulo-smartphone2-grande">Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro</h3>

                <a class="foto-smartphone2-grande" title="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro" href="#">
                <img class="foto-smartphone2-grande" src="smartphone1.jpg" alt="Foto del Redmi Note 8 Pro"> </a>

                <table class="tabla-smartphone2-grande">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ESPECIFICACIONES</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Almacenamiento</td>
                            <td>32GB/64GB/128GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Memoria RAM</td>
                            <td>6GB</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara frontal</td>
                            <td>8 Megapixeles</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camara trasera</td>
                            <td>4 camaras: 32mp,8mp,5mp,2mp</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table class="precio-smartphone2-grande">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>230$</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <a class="comprar-smartphone2-grande" href="#">Comprar</a>
                
            </div>
```

Comment: sigo teniendo problemas con el precio y el boton de compra

Comment: ¿Qué problemas son?

Comment: me aparecen muy por debajo de donde deberian de estar, al menos en mi pantalla

Comment: Si quieres puedes hacer un dibujo y mostrar donde quisieras que apareciera.

Comment: solucione varios de los problemas q tenia, la subi a un hosting gratis para ver como se veia en movil y en pc, en pc todo bien pero en movil los productos se ven muy alargados. le cambie la propiedad height y se ve bien en local pero el servidor como que le pone height al 60% SIEMPRE, eso es cosa del server o es por algo mio, te dejo el link para q veas de que hablo: free.zz.com.ve